# Multiple Backgrounds: Semi-Transparent Color on a BG

Tags: css, background, background-image, background-color

I am trying to create a background with a semi-transparent color on top of a background image. Right now I am using RGBA for the semi transparency of the color background layer, but the webpage only shows the image.

What I am trying to do is make an element go behind and not be visible when the page is scrolled and that element goes behind my fixed header, it looks bad if there is text under a header.

Feel free to ask for clarification.

Images:
What it is when not scrolled: http://prntscr.com/7llsd8
Scrolled: http://prntscr.com/7lls40

Code:

```css
#headerbg {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
  background: rgba(255, 153, 0, 0.79), url(../images/bg.png);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 18px -1px rgba(21, 20, 19, 1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 18px -1px rgba(21, 20, 19, 1);
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 18px -1px rgba(21, 20, 19, 1);
}
```

```html
<div id="headerbg">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="five columns">
        <img src="images/thv-header.png" id="header">
      </div>
      <div class="seven columns">
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#designers">Designers</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the updated code below.. Now Header has **background-color and multiple background images**

```css
#headerbg {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: rgba(255, 153, 0, 0.79);
  background-image: url(http://www.transparenttextures.com/patterns/back-pattern.png), url(http://www.transparenttextures.com/patterns/batthern.png);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 18px -1px rgba(21, 20, 19, 1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 18px -1px rgba(21, 20, 19, 1);
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 18px -1px rgba(21, 20, 19, 1);
}
```

```html
<div id="headerbg">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="five columns">
        <img src="images/thv-header.png" id="header">
      </div>
      <div class="seven columns">
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#designers">Designers</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I used a linear gradient to fake a background and it worked!

```css
background:linear-gradient(rgba(255,
154,
0,
0.79),
rgba(255,
154,
0,
0.79)),
url(../images/bg.png) no-repeat left top fixed;
```